# Looping through Columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select a particular range of values from a particular column instead of the entire column. This is my code. Pls help.

```
Option Explicit

Public i As Long
Public SubIsRunning As Boolean

Sub initiatesubs()

    If Not SubIsRunning = True Then
        i = 3
        Call copyvalues
        SubIsRunning = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub copyvalues()

    Sheets(2).Columns(i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("C11:C90").Value
    Sheets(3).Columns(i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("U11:U90").Value
    Sheets(2).Range("B11:B90").Value = Sheets(1).Range("L11:L90").Value
    Sheets(3).Range("B11:B90").Value = Sheets(1).Range("L11:L90").Value

    i = i + 1

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:04:00"), "copyvalues"
    Debug.Print Now + TimeValue("00:04:00")

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the complete loop. The easiest way to do this is using offset:    sheets(1).range(“c11”).offset(i-1).value

Comment: have edited the code.

Comment: Sorry, I think you need to study a little about programming - it seems that you do not know the concept of loops? ( “for” loops and “while” loops)

Comment: I agree. But I do know about these loops. Just that I am looping on time and not on counters. I dont want a variable 'i' to run from 1 to 'n' during every 4 minute intervals.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now what you are trying to do. Let's see if we can fix your code. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the time now to complete the answer, but the code below will get you started. You'll need a condition to stop the looping when you reach row 90

```
Option Explicit

Public i As Long
Public SubIsRunning As Boolean

Sub initiatesubs()
  If Not SubIsRunning = True Then
    i = 3
    Call copyvalues
    SubIsRunning = True
  End If
End Sub

Sub copyvalues()

   Sheets(2).Columns(i).Value =        Sheets(1).Range("C11").offset(i-3).Value

   Sheets(3).Columns(i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("U11").offset(i-3).Value

   Sheets(2).Range("B11").offset(i-3).Value =         Sheets(1).Range("L11").offset(i-3).Value

   Sheets(3).Range("B11").offset(i-3).Value = Sheets(1).Range("L11").offset(i-3).Value

   i = i + 1

  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:04:00"), "copyvalues"
  Debug.Print Now + TimeValue("00:04:00")
End Sub
```